# How to evaluate $\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(x\right)}{1+x}\:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, polylogarithm

I am trying to evaluate
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(x\right)}{1+x}\:dx$$
But I am not sure what to do since integration by parts is not possible here.

I tried using a trilogarithm functional equation and got the following integrals.
$$-\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-x\right)}{1+x}\:dx-\underbrace{\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)}{1+x}\:dx}_{J}+\zeta (3)\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)}{1+x}\:dx$$
$$+\frac{1}{6}\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^3\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)}{1+x}\:dx+\zeta (2)\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)}{1+x}\:dx-\frac{1}{2}\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1-x\right)}{1+x}\:dx$$
All the integrals here are actually manageable except $J$.

Any idea on how to evaluate the main integral differently or the integral $J$? Thank you.

Comment: Just for answer checking: $$I=2 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi ^2 \zeta (3)}{3}-\frac{85 \zeta (5)}{16}-\frac{3}{8} \zeta (3) \log ^2(2)-\frac{1}{60} \log ^5(2)+\frac{1}{36} \pi ^2 \log ^3(2)+\frac{1}{360} \pi ^4 \log (2)$$

Comment: And $$J=-2 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{3 \pi ^2 \zeta (3)}{32}+\frac{311 \zeta (5)}{64}+\frac{7}{16} \zeta (3) \log ^2(2)+\frac{\log ^5(2)}{60}-\frac{11}{72} \pi ^2 \log ^3(2)-\frac{49 \pi ^4 \log (2)}{1440}$$

Comment: @Iridescent Thanks for posting these, seems they are quite tough, btw would you please tell me the closed form for $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_n^3}{\left(2n+1\right)^2}$?

Comment: Sure $$S=48 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{7 \pi ^2 \zeta (3)}{24}-\frac{1271 \zeta (5)}{32}-\frac{2}{5}  \log ^5(2)-\frac{1}{3} \pi ^2 \log ^3(2)+\frac{61}{240} \pi ^4 \log (2)$$

Comment: I was able to boil the integral $I$ down to the evaluation of $\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(x\right)}}{1+x}$. Not sure if that helps much, but I feel like that is progress of a sort.